# JodaTime doesn't fail on mismatched day of week and month

Tags: java, jodatime

In the following piece of code, I expected an exception to be thrown because the day of week doesn't match the day of month. I couldn't find anything in the [DateTimeFormat Javadocs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) to say anything either way about being "strict" over such mis-matches, but I was confused that such bad data was allowed through. Have I misunderstood anything or is this a conscious design decision that I should deal with in some other way?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT_LONG_DATE = //
         DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, d MMMM yyyy")//
               .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Melbourne"));
   final String text = "Friday, 1 February 2016"; // Wrong.
   final DateTime parsed = DATE_FORMAT_LONG_DATE.parseDateTime(text);
   System.out.println(text);
   System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT_LONG_DATE.print(parsed));
}
```

and output:

```
Friday, 1 February 2016
Friday, 5 February 2016
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it does - as [documented](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (emphasis mine):

> Parsing builds up the resultant instant by 'setting' the value of each parsed field from largest to smallest onto an initial instant, typically 1970-01-01T00:00Z. This design means that day-of-month is set before day-of-week. **As such, if both the day-of-month and day-of-week are parsed, and the day-of-week is incorrect, then the day-of-week overrides the day-of-month. This has a side effect if the input is not consistent.**

I agree this is unfortunate - but you could always reformat afterwards and check whether the values are different.

Comment: Thanks Jon - the answer was in DateTimeFormatter's javadocs, not DateTimeFormat. Will have to remember this lesson!